# Start up a @WebServlet BEFORE SpringBootApplication's ApplicationContextInitializer beans are initialized

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets, spring-boot

I have a simple @WebServlet defined as follows, whose purpose is to construct a couple of static ApplicationContextInitializer beans, which are then required in my Spring Boot Application (for the record, I am implementing ServletContextListener because I also need to add some attributes to the ServletContext).

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/blah"}, loadOnStartup = -1000)
public class MyServlet implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext(MyConfiguration.class);
        Application.logitContextInitializer = context.getBean(LogitContextInitializer.class);
        Application.configWsClientInitializer = context.getBean(ConfigWsClientInitializer.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }

}
```

My Spring Boot Application looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static LogitContextInitializer logitContextInitializer;
    public static ConfigWsClientInitializer configWsClientInitializer;

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder in) {
        in.application().addInitializers(logitContextInitializer, configWsClientInitializer);

        SpringApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder = in.sources(Application.class);
        return applicationBuilder;
    }

}
```

However, when running my application, either by deploying to a dedicated Tomcat Server, or triggering programmatically, e,g.:

```
    new Application().configure(
            new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyServlet.class, Application.class)).run(args);
```

I cannot find a way to trigger MyServlet to start up **before** the ApplicationContextInitializer beans get initialized. I thought the loadOnStartup property in my @WebServlet might be the answer here but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Can you provide some background on what you're trying to do? You seem to have a second application context (configured with `MyConfiguration.class`) that you're using to create a couple of beans and then inject them into a Spring Boot application. Why not create the two initialisers (using whatever approach you want) in your `configure` so method?

Comment: Sure, the main reason comes down to the fact that I need to set some attributes on the ServletContext (which I understand should be shared across servlets). This is why I am starting up `MyServlet` first - so I can grab the context and set those attributes. `LogitContextInitializer` within my main servlet then requires those attributes during initialization.

Comment: I realised I didn't quite answer your question - I should also add that the initializer two beans which I'm creating in `MyServlet` are injecting @Value properties, which will depend upon the Spring profile which is being used (local/test/dev/sit/prd) - I can't do that inside the `configure` method of my application context because I don't think property placeholders have been resolved at that point (in fact, `ConfigWsClientInitializer` itself is responsible for defining a PropertySource).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to partially solve this by overriding the onStartup method of SpringBootServletInitializer, e.g.:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private final StartupHandler startupHandler = new StartupHandler();

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        startupHandler.handle(servletContext);
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder in) {
        startupHandler.addInitializersToApplication(in);
        return in.sources(Application.class);
    }
```

StartupHandler is a new class responsible for creating my initializer beans and setting properties on the ServletContext, within the **handle** method. The **addInitializersToApplication** method is then responsible for making use of those initializer beans.

The only case this doesn't work in is when I run locally (mvn spring-boot:run...) as opposed to deploying to a dedicated Tomcat - in the former case, my main method never calls onStartup. I could probably fix this if I spent some more time playing around with it, however for my specific use-case it's not important when running locally so I'm sticking with the solution I have.